# mnesia files damaged need to forensically dump everything

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have damaged my Mnesia database beyond repair as a result of overestimating the fragility of the implementation. When I try Mnesia API the records I need are not visible even though they keys are visible in the file. Even though the documentation indicates that Mnesia artifacts are DETS files they cannot be opened with or identified as DETS artifacts. PS: dump_to_textfile() does not work either.

Comment: Can you explain how `mnesia:dump_to_textfile/1` is not working? Do you get an error or is the call successful and the `mnesia:load_textfile/1` function call fails to import the data?

Comment: @Stratus3D my reference to dump_to_textfile() was just a PS.  The accompanying documentation suggests it's just for educational purposes. The bigger issue is that I was not able to extract the data from the DB and even though the documentation also indicates that it's either DETS or ETS I was not able to open any of the Mnesia data files.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I was able to dump my DB. It did not end my Mnesia problems but it gave me options I did not have before.

SETUP:
Originally I had implemented a master-master mnesia cluster. (read the docs). It turns out that not even the most seasoned Erlang programmer uses Mnesia replication as there are to many flaws. In fact I come to this information from the Erlang inner circle and a few L1 teams too. In my case, however, the work was already in production. And that's when problems started.

We started getting DB consistency errors and, my favorite, network or DB partition errors. It takes a very highly skilled and knowledgeable individual to recover as well as a lot of planning and code in advance; which I did not have.

Ultimately I took two steps. (a) removed the second app so that even though the DB was in a master-master cluster; one was a slave because it was never used as a master. (b) In a second implementation I split the cluster so that the app ran on a single node with a single DB. #a was in production and #b was the warm standby. Replication was manual as writes were very rare.

In the single node deployment there are two nodes.  The first node is the application; app@ks and on the same hardware was an "erl" node when I needed to rpc into the app and see how things were going.

MY SOLUTION:
when I posted this question I was trying to dump the contents of my Mnesia DB. I was having a number of problems because I was trying to access the DB from the admin node as the application node was operational.

Because I was trying to access the mnesia lib from the erl node the DB was not LOCAL to the erl node and so dump_to_textfile produced an empty file. I eventually had success when I used rpc to tell the app@ks node to dump.

STILL UNDEFINED
When I launched the admin node I set the mnesia dir parameter to the same folder as the app@ks node. I have a vague memory that this is undesirable.

There are many more Mnesia issues to solve but none that refer to the problem I reported. But I still do not know how to extract the raw data from the various DB files.